# How to use aggregation with nested document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested, aggregation

I'm new to mongoose, I'm confuse while create the query. Can you help me?
I have a movie document like this :

```
"movies": [
        {
            "id": "635611395a71beb6c5bf0b4d",
            "title": "Mission: Impossible - Fallout",
            "createdAt": "2022-10-24T04:14:54.445Z",
            "cast": [
                {
                    "actor": "635350c581d5b60383f0c4be",
                    "roleAs": "Ethan Hunt",
                    "leadActor": true,
                    "_id": "635658c18b9e50facd7f1fd1"
                },
                {
                    "actor": "63560bf55a71beb6c5bf0b1f",
                    "roleAs": "Ilsa Faust",
                    "leadActor": false,
                    "_id": "635658c18b9e50facd7f1fd2"
                }
            ],
            "poster": {
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/v1666603204/vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep.jpg",
                "public_id": "vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep",
                "responsive": [
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_640/v1666603204/vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep.jpg",
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_50/v1666603204/vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep.jpg"
                ]
            },
            "reviews": {
                "ratingAvg": "5.0",
                "reviewCount": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "635614855a71beb6c5bf0bdc",
            "title": "Spider-Man: No Way Home",
            "createdAt": "2022-10-24T04:28:58.286Z",
            "cast": [
                {
                    "actor": "635350a881d5b60383f0c4b8",
                    "roleAs": "Peter Parker",
                    "leadActor": true,
                    "_id": "636a2d6520cf4cf14a11ef95"
                },
                {
                    "actor": "635611eb5a71beb6c5bf0b99",
                    "roleAs": "MJ",
                    "leadActor": false,
                    "_id": "636a2d6520cf4cf14a11ef96"
                }
            ],
            "poster": {
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/v1667902823/tajzr9hpulvzqoytgpxu.jpg",
                "public_id": "tajzr9hpulvzqoytgpxu",
                "responsive": [
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_640/v1667902823/tajzr9hpulvzqoytgpxu.jpg",
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_470/v1667902823/tajzr9hpulvzqoytgpxu.jpg",
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_50/v1667902823/tajzr9hpulvzqoytgpxu.jpg"
                ]
            },
            "reviews": {
                "ratingAvg": "8.0",
                "reviewCount": 2
            }
        },
```

This is my desired result:

```
{
            "id": "635611395a71beb6c5bf0b4d",
            "title": "Mission: Impossible - Fallout",
            "createdAt": "2022-10-24T04:14:54.445Z",
            "cast": [
                {
                    "actor": "635350c581d5b60383f0c4be",
                    "roleAs": "Ethan Hunt",
                    "leadActor": true,
                    "_id": "635658c18b9e50facd7f1fd1"
                },
                {
                    "actor": "63560bf55a71beb6c5bf0b1f",
                    "roleAs": "Ilsa Faust",
                    "leadActor": false,
                    "_id": "635658c18b9e50facd7f1fd2"
                }
            ],
            "poster": {
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/v1666603204/vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep.jpg",
                "public_id": "vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep",
                "responsive": [
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_640/v1666603204/vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep.jpg",
                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/debfn35m1/image/upload/c_scale,w_50/v1666603204/vczxb7lgbonjn8ydsyep.jpg"
                ]
            },
            "reviews": {
                "ratingAvg": "5.0",
                "reviewCount": 2
            }
        },
```

Im trying to write a filter function to get all movie that has Tom Cruise with actorId as a parameter but cannot get the result.
Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: @Ipizzinidev ok i already posted it

Answer (score 0):

Since your actor id is inside a cast array with key actor you must specify your key while match, check the updated code below

```
exports.actorAggregation = (actorId) => {
    return [
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "Movie",
          localField: "cast",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "actorFilter",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$cast" },
      {
        $match: {
          "cast.actor._id": { $in: [actorId] }, // or "cast.actor": { $in: [actorId] },
          status: { $eq: "public" },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          title: 1,
          poster: "$poster.url",
          responsivePosters: "$poster.responsive",
          createdAt: "$createdAt",
        },
      },
    ];
};
```